# Algebra Practice Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

(a) A > B

(b) A < B

(c) A = B

(d) not enough information

(d) is my answer because the information that x != 0 is not showed. 
However the correct answer is (c), according to the book Manhattan Algebra-GRE-Strategy-Guide.

So which one is correct please? Thank you.

Comment: $x-1=2x\Rightarrow -1=x$, (c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Provided* that $x\neq 0$, the correct answer is (c). In such expressions, the possibility for the denominator being 0 is generally ruled out. As such, however, the ambiguity will persist.

Comment: but x≠0 is not provided, so should it be (d) instead?

Comment: In a strict sense, I'd say yes. Are such conditions taken into consideration in other questions too?

Comment: Yes, for example, in another question they gave the function f(x) = square(x-4) + squareroot(x+3) + 5/(x+2) and asked to indicate ALL values of x is f(x) defined, with: (a) -5 (b) -4 (c) -3 (d) -2 (e) -1. Their answers were (c) and (e).

Comment: This problem *is* slightly different, in the sense that it is asking you if the expression is sensible for particular values of $x$. Your original question contains an expression where it is generally assumed that the denominator doesn't take 0, stated or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the answer by applying some algebra as such:

$\frac{x-1}{x}=2$

Multiplying both sides by $x$ we get:

$x-1=2x$

Subtracting $x$ from both sides we get:

$x=-1$

So indeed, the correct answer is C.

Usually at a lower level authors of books don't mention mention conditions such as $x\neq 0$ as the goal is to make the students practice some algebra rules without much thinking, however your reasoning is correct, the whole equation wouldn't be defined if we have $x=0$ but again, such things are just automatically assumed on such a level.

If you want to be more Mathematically correct which is a good practice, you could write something like "Assuming $x\neq 0$" then solve, this of course wouldn't apply to this particular case as it's a MCQ.

Comment: Apparently the OP's question is not concerned with algebraic manipulation, but with the fact that the condition $x\neq 0$ has not been explicitly stated.

Comment: Oh, I was just editing to include that either way, thank you.